# How to order status updates on an event that has been completed

Tags: laravel

I have a list of events.

These events have status updates.

I'm paginating the statuses 10 per page.

When the page is loaded the status updates are ordered by `created_at desc`.

I also have links to order by ascending or descending
by passing ?sort=asc or ?sort=desc in the URL.

```
$sort = $request->has('sort') ? $request->query('sort') : 'desc';

if($sort == 'asc') {

    $statuses = $event->statuses()->oldest()->paginate(10);

} else {

    $statuses = $event->statuses()->latest()->paginate(10);

}
```

When an event has finished, it is marked as completed.
Then the event is ordered by `created_at desc`.
So that it reads from the beginning, like so:

```
if($sort == 'asc' || $event->completed) {

    $statuses = $event->statuses()->oldest()->paginate(10);

} else {

    $statuses = $event->statuses()->latest()->paginate(10);

}
```

However, if you then try and sort a completed event by statuses `created_at DESC` it sees that the event is completed and orders by ASC.

```
if($sort == 'asc' || $event->completed) {

    // If you go to ?sort=desc and the event has already been completed
    // This code will be executed, which I don't want.

    $statuses = $event->statuses()->oldest()->paginate(10);

} else {

    $statuses = $event->statuses()->latest()->paginate(10);

}
```

How do I adjust it so that you can sort a completed event by statuses DESC?

Comment: Pass orderby('completed','desc') after the first order by that is the created at. If the completed order by comes before the created at you will get that behaviour.

Comment: @oseintow The statuses don't have a 'completed' attribute. Only the event.

Comment: meaning the created_at is in a different table and the completed to is in another table

Comment: @oseintow I'm not sure I follow you? If it's not too much to ask could you do a quick code example?

Comment: I need to understand the table structure or see the models before i can write any code because i dont know what is happening under the statuses and latest(for latest i know you are ordering) function.

Comment: The Event model has a name and completed (default NULL). The Status model has an event_id and body (text), as well as created_at and updated_at.

Comment: I got side question: what is the point of putting brackets in the same line your `if` is and then put empty line before and after code?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The ` quotes in the last snippet are just to highlight that when you try and sort a completed event by statuses descending it won't do it as the event is completed and it will sort them in ascending order. I will remove the quotes.

Comment: If you are still fighting with this try https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable (I maintain it), or without package see where idea is from http://hack.swic.name/laravel-column-sorting-made-easy/